# Using two indefinite articles in a phrase

Tags: articles

In the phrase below, do we need the article to be used twice:

> A subject matter expert should be a member of a project team.

Comment: You need an article before _project team_ and an article before _member of [art] project team_. Which articles to use depends on what is new information and what isn't.

Comment: If the definiteness of the team is not important it could be rephrased as "a project team member".

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

Articles are used before nouns. ‘Member’ and ‘project team’ are nouns.

Articles

- A
- An
- The

It cannot be ‘a’ for ‘member’. Since we are referring to a member of a group, it must be ‘the’.  A is only used to be vague. Hence, it should be:

> …should be **a** member

It is ‘a’ for project team. This is referring to any
However, if you choose to at the name of the project team, you should write it like this.

> … of **the** [*give a name*]project team

[**##For more information##**](https://owl.purdue.edu/owl/general_writing/grammar/using_articles.html)